# How to delete all keyboard shortcuts in Chromium?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, chromium

We are currently working on an web application based on Chromium. The application might act as an OS for the user in the sense that it is impossible to exit the scope of the application (i.e. the page).

For this sake, I want to completely erase all shortcuts from Chromium, in a way that can be easily reproduced by an automatic installation.

However, I read that there is no easy way to handle shortcuts on Chromium : no config file, nothing in the console…
The only solution I found is to use extensions like [Shortcut manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgjjeipcdnnjhgodgjpfkffcejoljijf?hl=en-US), but this renders difficult the process of automatically configuring Chromium without shortcuts (and I am not sure these can absolutely eradicate all of them).

It seems that modifying [Chromium's sources](https://www.chromium.org/Home) is the way to go, but I could not figure out where such a process would take place. I am correct stating this ? Any help there would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I thought, the best solution is probably to change Chromium's sources. We finally managed to locate the list of the shortcuts in [accelerator_table.cc](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/chrome/browser/ui/views/accelerator_table.cc&q=accelerator_table.cc&sq=package:chromium&type=cs).

From there you can just simply comment the shortcuts you don't want to hear about, and recompile.